# The number of all pairwise non-isomorphic graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

How to prove that if $n = 4k + 2$ or $n = 4k + 3$, then the number of all pairwise non-isomorphic graphs with n vertices is even.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Presumably this is [OEIS A000088](http://oeis.org/A000088). Are there any odd numbers after $n=0,1,4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix a vertex set $V$ with $|V|=n$, where $n=4k+2$ or $n=4k+3$, for some nonnegative integer $k$.

Then $n(n-1)$ is even but not a multiple of $4$, hence ${\large{\binom{n}{2}}}$ is odd.

For any graph $G=(V,E)$, the isomorphism type of the complementary graph $G'=(V,E')$ is uniquely determined by the isomorphism type of $G$, and we have
$$
|E|+|E'|=\binom{n}{2}
$$
hence, since ${\large{\binom{n}{2}}}$ is odd, we get $|E|\ne|E'|$.

It follows that the graphs $G,G'$ are not isomorphic to each other.

Thus, the isomorphism types for graphs with vertex set $V$ come in pairs.

It follows the number of pairwise non-isomorphic graphs with vertex set $V$ is even.

Comment: Please tell me more about the types of isomorphism. What are types of isomorphism? Why, for any graph G, the isomorphism type of the complementary graph G ′ is uniquely determined by the isomorphism type of G? Why the isomorphism types for graphs with vertex set V come in pairs?

Comment: @Archangel_00000: Two graphs are said to have the same isomorphism type if they are isomorphic.

Comment: @Archangel_00000: As regards your second question, simply show that if $G$ is isomorphic to $H$, then $G'$ is isomorphic to $H'$, and then, since $(G')'=G$, the "if" becomes "if and only if".

Comment: @Archangel_00000: As regards your third question: $\;$Fix a vertex set $V$ with $|V|=n$, where $n$ satisfies the specified conditions. Let $S$ be a maximal set of pairwise non-isomorphic graphs with vertex set $V$ and with _less_ than ${\large{\binom{n}{2}/2}}$ edges, and let $S'$ be the set of complementary graphs $G'$ for $G\in S$. Then $S'$ is a maximal set of pairwise non-isomorphic graphs with vertex set $V$ and with _more_ than ${\large{\binom{n}{2}/2}}$ edges.

Comment: @Archangel_00000: Then $S\cap S'={\large{\varnothing}}$ and $S\cup S'$ is a maximal set of pairwise non-isomorphic graphs with vertex set $V$. Since the map $G\mapsto G'$ is a bijection from $S$ onto $S'$, it follows that $|S|=|S'|$, hence $|S\cup S'|$ is even.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Most graphs on $n$ vertices have a [complement graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph) which they are not isomorphic to
- How many edges does a self-complement graph on $n$ vertices have?
- When it that not an integer?